# ESDKLib by Johannes Bildstein - Argument Exception "The delegate must have only one target"

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, delegates, edsdk

I am using Canon SDK Example of Mr. Johannes Bildstein [EDSDKLib](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/688276/canon-edsdk-tutorial-in-csharp?msg=5092081) but I am getting Argument Exception with Message "The delegate must have only one target."

When I dig through I found `MainThread.Invoke(() =>` of `TakePhotoShutterAsync()` method is throwing exception. Kindly advise how I can fix this.

Below is my Stack Trace

```
at EOSDigital.API.GeneralExceptionHandler.BeginInvoke(Object sender, Exception ex, AsyncCallback callback, Object object)
   at EOSDigital.API.ErrorHandler.ReportError(Object sender, Exception ex)
   at EOSDigital.API.Camera.<TakePhotoShutterAsync>b__80_0(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Below is full method where I am getting exception.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Takes a photo with the current camera settings asynchronously with the PressShutterButton command
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException">Camera is disposed</exception>
    /// <exception cref="CameraSessionException">Session is closed</exception>
    /// <exception cref="SDKStateException">Canon SDK is not initialized</exception>
    public void TakePhotoShutterAsync()
    {
        CheckState();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
        {
            try
            {
                MainThread.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    SendCommand(CameraCommand.PressShutterButton, (int)ShutterButton.Completely);
                    SendCommand(CameraCommand.PressShutterButton, (int)ShutterButton.OFF);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { err.writeError(ex.Message); if (!ErrorHandler.ReportError(this, ex)) throw; }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Always post the stack trace if you have an exception.

Comment: @Voo  Updated Stack Trace Thanks!

Comment: looks like you have subscribed multiple times to the  ErrorHandler.SevereErrorHappened event and there's an exception in one of the SendCommand methods. You should be able to subscribe multiple times, that's an error on my part. As a workaround, subscribe only once.

Comment: Have you updated it in recent edits?